# Why does resize2fs shrink a partition by first moving blocks right after the end of the specified range? Can this be changed?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, resize2fs

I am currently shrinking a rather large partition with `resize2fs` in order to recover empty space in an LVM volume group.

The way I understand it, a file system shrink operation, for every block between (the last block in the file system) and (the block that should be the last one after the operation is done), does these things:

1. Check if it is used by any file
2. If it is, copy that block and all the blocks used by that file to the earliest position in the partition where they'll fit
3. Update the metadata so that the record for that block of files now points to the new location of the blocks

These steps do not appear to depend on the *order* in which these blocks are handled -- you could start moving the blocks at either end, and it would work either way. However, in a situation like this:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|    resize target          |      space to move blocks away from        |
|                           |                                            |
+-----------+---------------+---------+------+---------------+-----+-----+
|   used    |                         |  to  |               | to  |     |
|  space at |                         | move |               | move|     |
|   start   |                         | (1)  |               | (2) |     |
+-----------+-------------------------+------+---------------+-----+-----+
```

...`resize2fs` would move (1) first, and (2) second.

Why is that? To me it seems that doing (2) first has the advantage that, if the user decides that it would take too long for their liking to complete the resize operation, and they stop it halfway, then some progress will have been made, and if they choose to try again with a larger target size (a smaller shrinkage), then there's less to do the next time around.

In my case, I would be okay with a partial resize as long as I could shrink the LVM volume and use the spare LVM extents, but to do that would require freeing up space at the end of the file system, so I've been repeatedly running the `resize2fs` command and manually shrinking the volume by small increments. Is there a better way to do this?

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/663744/247373) is similar, it's about how to recover filesystem space in the other direction -- at the *start* of the partition, not the end.

Comment: You could probably do it that way, but this would increase filesystem fragmentation and would decrease performance of your harddisk (rotating disk). Of course, this wouldn't matter that much on a SSD drive. The resize2fs commands just works like a defrag tool (with some special settings).

Comment: @paladin Would it? The `resize2fs` tool already copies groups of blocks, it could just do the same here -- copying each block group, but iterating over the groups in reverse order. I suppose that each of the block groups represents a file, or a large piece of the file, so the fragmentation level shouldn't substantially change.

Comment: @Danya02 if `resize2fs` iterated over the groups in reverse order, it would have to deal with situations where it wants to move a later group to a location occupied by a yet-to-be-moved earlier group.

Comment: When you read a filesystem in "reverse" order you can't determine the beginning of a file until you've reached the beginning of the file. That means, if you don't search for the beginning of the file (which is time consuming), you may only copy block by block of that file which filesize you don't know. You may set a buffer size of course, but the bigger the buffer, the slower the copy, because you need to copy data from harddisk into main memory (or even more worse into a swap) and reverse. Otherwise when you just do it the normal way, the harddisk just may use its cache, which is faster.